# Consistency when multiple applications use the same database

Tags: mysql, spring, transactions, spring-data

If I have 2 or more Spring applications using the same mysql database. Will database keep consistency having Spring transactions from many applications?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use transactions to keep your database consistent, yes. Of course, if your consistency problem is not at a transaction level but on entity level, you will also need to configure something like optimistic/pessimistic locking, for example via Hibernate.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz thanks. Then, is database (mysql) handling transactions (`@Transactional`) behind?. Could you explain me more "transaction level" and "entity level"? thanks.